# Write a stack class that can return the size of the stack in constant time

Tags: stack

Write a stack class that can return the size of the stack in constant time.
The problem statement and solution is a little unclear for me. What if I have a variable that keeps track of the size. But this solution seems too easy and not related to stack.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect against stack underflow you probably already have a second pointer to the bottom/start of the stack. You can then calculate the difference between the two pointers.

That is practically equivalent to the explicit size counter you find too easy, though.